# How to create a 40hz Flickering Black/White Light in Kotlin (or Java)?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, timer, background-color

My goal: I want to create a black and white flickering video. The white flashes need to be 40hz. So basically I need to create 80 frames where there are 40 white and 40 black frames. The white flashes illustrate the flashes you get from a 40Hz LED Light Bulb.

This is the code I am using at the moment:

```
package com.example.java

import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.WindowInsets
import android.view.WindowManager
import android.widget.ImageView
import androidx.annotation.ColorRes
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import java.util.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var imgFlickr: ImageView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            window.insetsController?.hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars())
        } else {
            window.setFlags(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            )
        }
        supportActionBar?.hide()

        imgFlickr = findViewById(R.id.img_flickr)

        val timer = Timer()
        val timerBlack = FlickrTimer(R.color.black)
        val timerWhite = FlickrTimer(R.color.white)

        timer.schedule(timerBlack, 0, 12)
        timer.schedule(timerWhite, 0, 12)
    }

    private inner class FlickrTimer(@ColorRes val backgroundColor: Int) : TimerTask() {
        override fun run() {
            runOnUiThread {
                imgFlickr.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this@MainActivity, backgroundColor))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My question: to show 40 white images and 40 black images in 1 second, each picture should last *1 second/80 frames* = 0,0125 seconds = 12,5 milliseconds. However, the timer I am using does not support decimals. Does anyone know how to fix this, or maybe has a totally different idea to achieve this goal? I would be really glad!

Kind regards,

Mitch

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Thread.sleep(long millis, int nanos)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread#sleep(long,%2520int)) and use the `nanos` value for much finer-grained delays. The trouble is you're using `runOnUiThread` which posts a message to the main thread, and that will get around to processing it... sometime... it has things to do!

There's an answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31537003/is-it-necessary-to-use-a-separate-thread-when-using-surfaceview) with some links to a `SurfaceView` implementation that runs on its own dedicated thread (the Grafika link is broken but [the file is here](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/android/grafika/MultiSurfaceActivity.java)) and some other references. You can basically have your own `Surface` that you can draw to off the UI thread, and you can sleep that thread as much as you want, and draw a thing directly when it wakes.

Another issue is that as far as I'm aware, Android always renders natively at 60Hz, including using a `SurfaceView` ([details on the whole pipeline here](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html), but you're adding frames to a queue that's polled by the system). And there's no way to turn 60Hz into an even 40 by skipping frames, unless you're willing to skip every 3rd frame - I'm guessing that's a no-go for what you're doing!

I know some newer phones handle 120Hz, but I don't know how that works on Android. Maybe you need to start messing around with OpenGL, Vulkan or RenderScript - way beyond what I know, sorry!